# Error creating hive partitioned BigQuery table from Parquet

Tags: json, hive, google-bigquery

I am trying to create a partitioned BigQuery table from a hive source on GCS.

First, I created the definition file:

```
bq mkdef \
  --autodetect \
  --source_format=PARQUET \
  --hive_partitioning_mode=AUTO \
  --hive_partitioning_source_uri_prefix="gs://project-name/tablename" \
  "gs://project-name/tablename/*.parquet" > "def_file_name"
```

Then I tried to create the table:

```
bq mk --external_table_definition="<definition/file/path>" \
  "<project_id>:<dataset>.<table_name>"
```

However, the command failed with the error:

```
Error decoding YAML external table definition from file <filename>: unacceptable character #x0000: special characters are not allowed in <filename>, position 3
```

I notice that the error message specifies YAML, however the definition file was generated in JSON format. I would love to know what I am doing wrong!

Comment: Can you also add file name as sample here.

Comment: Are you following the restrictions for the partitions on the files on GCS. The files have to be organized in folders with the pattern `<key>=<value>` of the partitioned data. i.e: `gs://myBucket/myTable/dt=2019-10-31/lang=en/` if the data is partitioned in `2` fields `dt` and `lang`. The use of only the values are not supported , like `gs://myBucket/myTable/2019-10-31/en/`. Also, do you have any file that is not part of the data on the bucket ? remove it. Please show examples of how your data is organized (folders names).